# Largest reported speedup for a parallel computation?

Tags: reference-request, efficiency, parallel-computing

A parallel implementation of a computation is usually compared to a sequential version of the same computation.  The ratio of the time taken by the sequential version to the time taken by the parallel version is called the *speedup*.  So if 8 cores run their smaller parts of the computation in 2 time units, and one core runs the whole computation in 8 time units, then the speedup is 4.

> What is the largest speedup reported for a real computation?

It is possible to reach essentially infinite speedup in a search problem, since one of the parallel pieces of the search space may lead to a fast solution by that parallel instance, while the sequential solution has to work through the entire search space to get to that point.  More generally, I want to exclude any problem where one of the parallel processes can reach a shortcut.  So I am only interested in computations where the amount of work done by the parallel processes is the same as done by the sequential process.  This is common in solving PDEs by grid methods, or in discrete event simulation.
So with $n$ processors, one should never get more than $n$ speedup for these kinds of problems.

I would also like to exclude embarrassingly parallel problems like parallel rendering, since there one really has a vast number of independent tiny problems.  I am interested in problems where it is not possible to partition the computation into strictly disjoint pieces.

For a large speedup, one has to have many processors.  Given the restrictions on scope that I have conveniently labelled as "real computations", this question is then essentially about how efficiently the very large processor arrays that exist have been programmed.

I am aware of reported speedups of ~500 using arrays of GPUs, but surely larger speedups exist.

---

*Edit:* To address some of the comments, I dug up some further motivation, which will hopefully be precise enough for the tastes of those more mathematically inclined.  This is quite different in style from the above, so I append it here as a postscript.

For $n$ iid random variables $X_1, X_2,\dots, X_n$ with mean $\mu$,
denote their maximum by $X_{(n)}$ and their sum by $S_n$.
O'Brien has shown that $X_{(n)}/S_n \to 0$ [almost surely](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Almost_sure_convergence) as $n \to \infty$ iff $\mu < \infty$.

Letting $X_i$ be the time taken by the $i$-th processor to complete its task, and assuming that there is a timeout/recompute mechanism to ensure that $\mu$ is finite, this hints that the inverse of the speedup should be essentially unbounded.  (This is not necessarily the case: the techniques used may not carry over to the inverse, so I have to leave this a bit vague.)

This is a nice theoretical prediction, and the question arises: *is this prediction borne out in practice?*  Or do implicit dependencies or diverging behaviours of the different processors (i.e. a breakdown in the iid assumption) tend to curtail this supposedly unbounded increase?

The iid case corresponds to the embarrassingly parallel case.  Where the processors have to synchronize, independence breaks down.

My question can therefore also be rephrased as: how badly does non-negligible dependence between parts of a computation as seen in practice affect the large-scale speedups that have been demonstrated?  Given that [the bounds for expectation of the maximum in the non-independent case are quite weak](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/427162/3362), some pointers to empirical data would be useful.

- G. L. O'Brien, *[A Limit Theorem for Sample Maxima and Heavy Branches in Galton-Watson Trees](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3213043)*, Journal of Applied Probability **17** 539–545, 1980.

Comment: Are you interested in raw numbers, or relative speedup (speedup divided by number of cores)? In particular, figures for GPUs I have seen typically use many more cores than the obtained speedup while CPUs seem to support better relative speedup, but we have fewer of them.

Comment: I want the absolute speedup -- just how far can one go by using parallel processing, as opposed to how efficiently one uses available resources.

Comment: It is not clear if the [LINPACK benchmark used for the Top 500 Supercomputer list](http://www.top500.org/project/linpack/) would be considered not embarrassingly parallel--it has extremely limited communication requirements. If it is an acceptable benchmark, then the top list result could be used to generate a speedup ratio based on performance of a single core. Of course, defining the best result for a single core might be challenging--an FPGA programmed as a single vector processor core might beat even the best Intel processor core.

Comment: @AndrásSalamon: The sky is the limit, as long as you have sufficiently large instances. (By the way, the answers to this question will become outdated. How do you plan to keep the question interesting to keep around?)

Comment: @Raphael: I am more interested in an easy-to-find snapshot as of now.  As Massimo suggests, the actual speedup does not seem to be the main focus of most of the currently published results.  So it is not that easy to track down.

Comment: I'm strongly tempted to close this as NARQ. The set of valid problems is unclear, and as Raphael alludes to, achieved speedup is highly sensitive to architectural details that vary along lots of axes. This question could be a better fit if it asked about factors influencing speedup, i.e., why not all problems are embarrassingly parallel and why these may not even always scale perfectly to kinds of architectures.

Comment: @Patrick87: I am quite familiar with the things that affect speedup (one of these is what my MSc was about).  What I didn't know was precisely what I was asking about: how large a speedup has actually been achieved.  I got a nice answer, so I am happy.

Comment: I guess my point is that if you know enough about this not to need that information, you should understand why this isn't a very meaningful question.

Comment: @Patrick87: it is a highly meaningful question to me – I have not worked in parallel computing for a long time and was keen to find out what was now known.  Massimo furthermore provided some information I didn't even know to ask for, that the focus has shifted away from speedup.

Comment: @AndrásSalamon I understand why this information is important (to you) but I still feel this question is barely SE-good. Well, never mind. Regarding speedup: reporting *only* speedup is not very interesting since efficiency has become important (well, it was always important, but apparently ignored). As Massimo demonstrates, you can deduce speedup from any reasonable set of reported figures (imho, a set that does not allow that is not meaningful).

Comment: @Patrick87 I agree that this question should have a dimension that makes it "timeless". Maybe move from speedup to efficiency? That's not the number András needs, but makes current numbers comparable to future ones.

Comment: interesting ideas in the question but unfortunately feel its somewhat illposed also. there seems to be a total continuum of problems between "embarrassingly parallel" and "unparallelizable" (ie no gains from parallelism) and its in the nature of the problem itself, not so much related to how good your hardware is. basically, gains due to parallelism measure "interprocessor communication overhead". for some problems it is high, for others it is low. a somewhat related concept is "granularity" where "finegrained" problems are more parallelizable.

Comment: @vzn: your view of parallelism as a measure of interprocessor communication overhead is not quite correct. There are many others sources of problems that must be addressed to achieve good performances. For instance, (dynamic) load balancing), irregular domain partitioning, synchronization, processor idling, data replication, mapping, contention time to access the interconnection network, contention time to access shared data structure etc.

Comment: continued: Moreover, due to current performances of processors, fine grained decompositions are no longer effective; instead, a commonly adopted technique is agglomeration in higher dimensions, that leads to a corse grained decomposition.

Comment: @massimo ok the interprocess communication as the basic overhead is a simplification. your overview/insight on newer thinking is interesting, now if you could only cite a ref, it might come close to answering the question...

Comment: for starters here is some brief wikipedia info on [computing/parallelism granularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granularity#Computing) talking about some of the tradeoffs

Comment: see also [amdahls law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahmdal%27s_Law)

Comment: I know of at least one semifamous scientific project with very high scales of parallelization which would lead to very high speedups versus individual/sequential machines. however, the scientists are interested in/focused on doing analysis of the project/problem data, and not interested in quantifying the speedup, so they havent at all even attempted to measure/mention the speedup in their writeup.... so there are increasingly more projects like that, where the massive parallelism is in a way taken for granted along the way of some other scientific objective.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

John Gustafson observed and reported speedups in excess of 1024 on early 80's supercomputers; this led him to the concept of scaled speedup (Gustafson-Barsis law), in contrast to the pessimistic Amdahl-Ware law.

Right now, in the era of multicore parallel supercomputers equipped with hundreds of thousands or millions of cores, performances are more commonly reported in terms of petaflops and efficiency. For instance, the winners of the last Gordon Bell prize at the Supercomputing 2012 conference, established the current world record for an astrophysical [N-body simulation of one trillion particles performed on the full K computer](http://conferences.computer.org/sc/2012/papers/1000a005.pdf), which appears to be [number 4](http://top500.org/lists/2013/06/) in the June 2013 top 500 list. They reported 4.45 petaflops on 663,552 cores (the K computer was equipped with 82944 8-core processors in November 2012), and an efficiency (the ratio speedup/cores) of 42%. Translated in terms of speedup, that means a speedup of about 278,691.

Comment: The [Gordon Bell prize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordon_Bell_Prize) is definitely where you want to look.  The wikipedia page has pointers to the official pages that list all the previous winners.